# To remove tags containing particular subtag in xml parsing with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse XML file using BeautifulSoup in Python. The XML file is such as:

```
<x id = '123'>
<b><c>abcd</c>
</b>
</x>
<x id ='456'><z></z>
</x>
<x id ='567'><c>def</c>
</x>
```

If any outer tag `<x>` contains the sub tag `<c>`, I want to delete the whole tag . How should I do it in Python?

Comment: Do you want to delete both tags, or only the one containing `def`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find all the `x` tags using `find_all('x')`. Then if the tag contains a `<c>` tag (which can be checked by using `if x.find('c'):`) remove the tag using [`decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose).

```
xml = '''
<x id = '123'>
    <b><c>abcd</c></b>
</x>
<x id ='456'>
    <z></z>
</x>
<x id ='567'>
    <c>def</c>
</x>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')
for x in soup.find_all('x'):
    if x.find('c'):
        x.decompose()
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<x id="456">
<z></z>
</x>
```